# React MaterialUI Card: how to change Card's class on expand? -> Custom React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

There are 20 cards on the page.
MaterialUI Card has `onExpandChange` property where I can define an action like this:

```
<Card expandable={true} onExpandChange={this.clickHandle}>
```

In this action I can easily know if the clicked card is expanded or not, because the callback function is defined like this in the MaterialUI: `function(newExpandedState: boolean) => void`

```
clickHandle = (newExpandedState: boolean) => {
    //do something
}
```

Now I would like to change card's class, for example, give it class `expanded` when `newExpandedState` is `true`.

**The problem is** that I don't know how to tell this function which card has been expanded. Things like `onExpandChange={this.clickHandle(newState, 'card1')}` don't work. I have 20 cards on the page and I don't know which one should get `expanded` class. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to wrap the material-ui's card with your own custom card and add a state to it:
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'material-ui';

```
class MyCustomCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    expanded: null
  }

  toggleExpanded = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      expanded: !state.expanded
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return <Card expandable expanded={this.state.expanded} onExpandChange={this.toggleExpanded}>
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../MyCustomCard';

class App extends React.Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. And if I need to put CardHeader, CardActions, etc, or other properties of the Card itself, do I need to mention them in MyCustomCard or they will be inherited?

Comment: Yes, you would need to expose them to your custom component. I would recommend to expose only the ones you need. If you just want them all, spread attributes are useful for it (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes). You can use the children prop to use CardHeader, etc. as they should like:

<Card>{this.props.children}</Card>

Comment: Great! Glenn, please, can you edit your answer with more details? For example, if I want to use MyCustomCard with some specific Card properties, like: `initiallyExpanded`, `showExpandableButton`, `style`, `id`, etc.. different for different card. And adding some basic `CardHeader` and `CardText`, which can be different for different cards?

Comment: I used your solution and everything works except one thing: if I have `showExpandableButton={true}` the button will be there, but clicking on it does not expand the card. So the card can be expanded only when clicking on the CardTitle. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I know that I want it to be expandable, this is my part of customization. But even in this case: `<Card className={this.state.expanded ? 'controller-card expanded' : 'controller-card'} expandable={true} expanded={this.state.expanded} onExpandChange={this.clickHandle} showExpandableButton={true}>{this.props.children}</Card>` the button will be there, but will not trigger expanding of the card. The question is: how to make the button work?

Comment: I'm sorry it was a mistake in the solution. So instead of <Card expandable={true} onExpandChange={this.clickHandle}>... of course you need to use your state instead of the boolean: <Card expandable={true} expanded={this.state.expanded} onExpandChange={this.clickHandle}>. Will update the wrong answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with button, but regarding [this material UI API](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card) it should work like this already. Maybe can you send a fiddle or https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/nZj7Qm3Dp. If you slick on CardHeader "Tag information" - the Card will act as extandable. But if you click on the button in the CardHeader -> the Card doesn't react.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**1.** Maintain an `array` in `state` variable that will have the record of all the id's of card (any unique property of card) which are in **expanded state**.

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
      cardStatus: []
   }
}
```

**2.** Pass the unique value to each `onExpandChange` method:

```
onExpandChange={() => this.clickHandle(card.name)}
```

**3.** Now if `newExpandedState` is `true` the push that value inside `state array` otherwise remove it:

```
clickHandle(name, newExpandedState){
    let cardStatus = this.state.cardStatus.slice();
    if(newExpandedState)
        cardStatus.push(name);
    else{
        let index = this.state.cardStatus.indexOf(name);
        cardStatus.splice(index,1);
    }
    this.setState({cardStatus});        
}
```

**4.** Now when generating the card check if that `cardStatus array` has that unique property of card or not and then apply different `classNames`.

```
<Card className={this.state.cardStatus.indexOf(card.name) >= 0 ? 'expanded': 'not'}>
```

Comment: Nice idea. I did something similar but your solution is cleaner. I just added the state argument here, to get the state of the card: `onExpandChange={(state) => this.clickHandle3('card1', state)}`. Still I would really want to know if it's possible somehow to directly send the 'card's object' inside that function.

Comment: card's object? data from where you are generating the card ?

Comment: I mean that if I make a breakpoint in the `clickHandle` function, then in "Local" I can see the `newExpandedState` variable, and `this` that refers to the card itself with its className and all the rest. But if I make `console.log(this)`, I retrieve, of course, the component itself, not the card. Is it possible to get to the "this" of the expanded card? It is there somewhere, but where?

Comment: write it like this: `onExpandChange={(newExpandedState, e) => this.clickHandle(card.name, newExpandedState, e)}` now this `e object` should have the card details, try `e.target`.

Comment: Mayank, I did exactly what you said, but I get `undefined` if I do `console.log(e)` in the clickHandle function. Did you try it and it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Just to share the result:

Finally got it working with the help of @glenn-reyers and got this code for the CustomCard component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card} from 'material-ui/Card';


class CustomCard extends React.Component<any, any> {
  state = {
    expanded: false
  }

  handleExpandChange = (expanded) => {
    this.setState({expanded: expanded});
  };

  render() {
    return 
        <Card 
            className={this.state.expanded ? 'controller-card expanded' : 'controller-card'} 
            expandable={true} 
            expanded={this.state.expanded} 
            onExpandChange={this.handleExpandChange}>
                {this.props.children}
        </Card>
  }
}

export default CustomCard;
```

Working fiddle is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/76O8pnW9Q