# ReactJS selecting an element uniquely from a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I am doing a todo app to practice React. I hit a blocker and now I'm trying to figure out how to uniquely edit a card.

Currently when I click on edit, all my cards are set to `isEditing == true`. I've tried adding a key and index, but doesn't seem to uniquely identify the selected card.

As seen in my gif:

[image]

Obviously the expected outcome is that it should only set `isEditing == true` to the selected card.

See Code below.

**For more context:** *there is stateful component that passes the props to this component, I'm using `react-bootstrap` (hence `Panel`, `Button`), and I removed some code for brevity (`construct` and whatnot).*

```
    edit() {
        this.setState({
            isEditing: true
        })
    }

    renderEditDoneButtons() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.edit}>edit</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    renderNote(note) {
        return (
            <p> {note} </p>
        )
    }

    renderCard(note, i) {
        return (
            <Panel key={i}
                   index={i}>
                {
                    this.state.isEditing ? 
                    this.renderForm() : 
                    this.renderNote(note.note)
                }
            </Panel>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.notes.map(this.renderCard)}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: How is the `renderEditDoneButtons()` button linked with the same id to the card? If the button has the same Id as the card you can create an array which has an individual edit state for each card. Or you could have a varaible which stores the id of the card currently being edited and you can show that card accordingly

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409731/react-materialui-card-how-to-change-cards-class-on-expand-custom-react-com

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit only one at a time? Or do you want to allow the user to essentially toggle the edit on/off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three are changing based on your single `isEditing` state, which is why you're seeing all three being shown when you click any of the "Edit" buttons. Instead of a single `isEditing` key in state, use an array to maintain all three states like so:

```
constructor(props) {

  super(props);

  // Sets a true/false editing state for all three panels
  this.state = {
    editingPanels: Array(3).fill(false)
  }
}

edit(i) {

    // Switches editing state to false/true for given i
    const editingPanels = this.state.editingPanels.slice();
    editingPanels[i] = !editingPanels[i];

    this.setState({
        editingPanels: editingPanels
    })
}

renderEditDoneButtons(i) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={()=>this.state.edit(i)}>edit</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

renderNote(note) {
    return (
        <p> {note} </p>
    )
}

renderCard(note, i) {
    return (
        <Panel key={i}
               index={i}>
            {
                this.state.editingPanels[i] ? 
                this.renderForm() : 
                this.renderNote(note.note)
            }
        </Panel>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.notes.map(this.renderCard)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `const editingPanels = this.state.editingPanels.slice();` could this have been refactored to `const editingPanels = this.state.editingPanels`

Comment: @e_mam106 correct - Facebook recommends using slice if you want to track history of user input, so I do it out of habit :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate component for each todo list item and use it inside the map method.The following example gives an idea on how to implement this.I am using another example as you have not provided the full code.

```
class EditText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {value:props.data,newValue:'hi'}
    this.editValue = this.editValue.bind(this)
  }
  editValue() {
    this.setState({value:this.state.newValue})
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {this.state.value}
      <button onClick={this.editValue}>Change text to Hi</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {tempDate : ['hello','how']}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      {this.state.tempDate.map(data=>(<EditText data={data}/>))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have state variable isEditing for each particular card.
If there are 3 cards, you need to have 3 variables.

**Edit 1 :-** 
Example is already shared by Kody R.

One Thing i noticed is instead of hard-coding array size to 3,we  could assign array size by number of notes recieved in props.

```
this.state = {
    editingPanels: Array(3).fill(false)
  }
```

To

```
this.state = {
    editingPanels: Array(this.props.notes.length).fill(false)
  }
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers !!